# Reinstall Windows 10 on Bitlocker drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bitlocker, reinstall

I have a Windows 10 PC that I cannot access because the hard-drive is blocked with Bitlocker and I do not have the Bitlocker key. Is it in any way possible to reinstall Windows 10 on the Bitlocker drive?

I know that I can wipe out the drive, create a new partition, and do a clean installation of Windows 10. However, that's my last resort, as I would have to buy a Windows 10 key and that's not really necessary, as Windows 10 is *already* installed in the PC, so it would be a waste. What I want to do is to reinstall Windows 10 on the same drive (and with the same license key) and make it Bitlocker-free. Note that I do not have access to the license key since I am talking about a company PC (Windows 10 came preinstalled)

Comment: If Windows 10 was activated, it will automatically activate again. Also, shouldn’t this be your company’s problem? Surely they’re using a volume license.

Comment: If I reinstall Windows 10, how can Windows detect the license if the (re)installation process will remove everything from the HD? The company will allow me to install another OS, but somehow when they do the installation they insist on installing Windows with Bitlocker. So I want to reinstall Windows without Bitlocker as explained in the question

Comment: “However, that's my last resort, as I would have to buy a Windows 10 key” - This is absolutely false.  What edition of Windows are you running?  If you don’t have the BitLocker key then it will be impossible to disable BitLocker protection, worth pointing out that any configuration change will result in that recovery key being required to boot Windows.  Unauthorized changes to company assets would be grounds to immediate dismissal at my company

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author is attempting to use unauthorized configured Windows installation on a company asset.  The user isn’t an Administrator, and thus doesn’t have the authority, or the BitLocker recovery key that’s required to do what they want.  Questions about changing corporate configurations are out of scope.

Comment: What if the computer was mine and somehow I: 1) forgot my access credentials; 2) forgot/lost my Bitlocker key? Would the question be still out of scope? Can you also explain why you think my last resort is "absolutely false"? How can I reinstall Windows 10 with the same license key, but _without_ having access to the Bitlocker key? If you say this is absolutely false, then I assume there is a way to do that

Comment: see if it's helpful to you:https://www.repairwin.com/how-to-remove-bitlocker-protection-without-the-bitlocker-recovery-key-or-password/

Comment: @GloriaGu thanks a lot for your comment, I followed that guide and the problem is now solved!